# Conditional Probaility?

Tags: probability

With this question- Charlie recorded the colour of 25 cards as they drove past her school. Four of the cars were red. Based on these results what is the probability that the next car to drive past the school is red?

Is the answer just 4/25?

Or is it a conditional probability, if so how would you attempt to solve it?

Comment: Are you familiar with Poisson Point processes?

Comment: No, not really. This only for basic probalility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question calls for more of a statistical viewpoint.

Cars follow some unknown distribution of colors, but we can assume that the color of the next car we see is independent of those that came before - because it's a different car. The probability that a random unknown car is red is some unknown $p$. We have observed $4$ of $25$ cars that are red. What is our best estimate of $p$?

Well, how do we define "best" here? There are several choices. One of the most natural is the [maximum likelihood estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation), which leads to that ratio $\frac{4}{25}$.
But, of course, that's not the only way. Suppose instead that we didn't see any red cars? Should we estimate a probability of zero? Probably not - there are red cars out there somewhere. This leads to the [Bayes estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator). If we take as a prior estimate (before any observation) that $p$ comes from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, then the estimate after seeing $k$ red cars out of $n$ is $\frac{k+1}{n+2}$; $\frac{5}{27}$ for our observations here. This gets closer to the MLE as the number of observations grows, but there will always be that slight bias toward $\frac12$.

The problem of parameter estimation from observation of random variables is the fundamental problem of a large branch of statistics, and it has enough depth to it to build a whole discipline around. Even in this simple case, there's enough of that depth that I can't just give you a number.